# How do I disable rotation in all activities which belong to my Android application?

Tags: java, android

I'm working on an Android open source application. This application contains many activities.

I want to deactivate the rotation in all activities. How to do that in [Java](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_%28programming_language%29) and not in XML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In XML:

```
<activity android:name=".SomeActivity"
          android:label="@string/app_name"
          android:screenOrientation="portrait">
```

In Java:

```
setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

Sadly, you have to do it for every activity or create an abstract PortraitActivity, which will be extended by all your application's activities.